# ReactJS how to use if function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, deep-learning

This will sound super basic but I have no experience with React.
My app https://eyerecycle-eb1db.web.app/ takes images, and feeds back prediction from a trained model, I want to add conditions so that if it predicts metal etc. I can then add text about the material, can anyone advise what the most elegant solution will be for this using react?

Current Landing page snippet:

```
            </div>
            <div className="row">
                <div className="col-12 message">
                    This simple waste image classifier can identify the following materials from an image:
                   <div> Metal, Plastic, Paper, Cardboard or Trash</div>
                    <div>Upload your image below:</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="row">
                <div className="col-12 center-div choose-file">
                    <input type="file" name="file" id="file" class="choose" onChange={this.props.handleChange} />
                    <label for="file">Choose a file</label>
```

current result page snippet:

```
 render() {
    return (
        <div className="container">
            <div className="row center-div preds">
                <div className="col-12 center-div pred-cat"> Predicted Category: {this.props.result['category']}</div>
            </div>
            <div className="row center-div probs-outer">
                <div className="col-12 center-div probs-title">
                    Probabilities for each class:
                </div>
                <div className="col-12 center-div probs">
                    <b>Metal: </b> {this.props.result['probs']['metal']}
                </div>
                <div className="col-12 center-div probs">
                   <b>Plastic: </b> {this.props.result['probs']['plastic']}
                </div>
                <div className="col-12 center-div probs">
                    <b>Cardboard: </b>{this.props.result['probs']['cardboard']}
                </div>
                <div className="col-12 center-div probs">
                    <b>Paper: </b>{this.props.result['probs']['paper']}
                </div>
                <div className="col-12 center-div probs">
                    <b>Glass: </b> {this.props.result['probs']['glass']}
                </div>
                <div className="col-12 center-div probs">
                    <b>Trash:</b>: {this.props.result['probs']['trash']}
```

Thanks

Comment: What specifically do you want to show and where and what have you tried? Even sudo code would help show what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

The general pattern for this in React is to use the `&&` operator, like so:

```
const MyComponent = props => {
    const [show, setShow] = useState(false);

    return <>
      {!show && <button onClick={() => setShow(true)}
      {show && <div>Something!</div>}
    </>;
};
```

The above component would only show a button at first, and then when that button was clicked (changing the state) it would instead only show the `div`.  This works because in Javascript, if you do:

```
someBoolean && somethingElse
```

it will evaluate to `someBoolean` (if it's `false`) or the `somethingElse` (if it's `true`).  The same principle is often used with the `||` operator set defaults, eg.:

```
const someValue = someOtherValue || defaultValue;
```

Also, as a side note:

```
this.props.result['probs']['plastic']
```

can just be:

```
this.props.result.probs.plastic
```